# Циклическая сборка gulp watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-uglify, gulp-concat

Есть проект, его структура:

[image: sp]

Когда я выполняю `gulp watch` запускается gulp, при изменении scss-файлов все срабатывает правильно, а когда изменяю js то сборка идет бесконечно.

gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var compass = require('gulp-compass');

gulp.task('compress-js', function() {
    return gulp.src([
            './www/js/jquery/**/*.js',
            './www/js/vendor/**/*.js',
            './www/js/lib/**/*.js',
            './www/js/common/app.js',
            './www/js/pages/**/*.js',
            './www/js/common/main.js',
            '!./www/js/combine.js'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('combine.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/js/'));
});

gulp.task('compress-css', function() {
    return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
                .pipe(compass({
                    config_file: './scss/config.rb',
                    css: './www/css',
                    sass: './scss'
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'));
});


gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['./scss/**/*.scss'], ['compress-css']);
    gulp.watch(['./www/js/**/*.js'], ['compress-js']);
});
```

Подскажите что здесь неправильно?

И еще, непонятный момент, если я положу `jquery.js` в папку `vendor`, то как мне сказать gulp'у, что jquery должна жаться первой, а за ней уже другие скрипты? И еще, интересно, можно ли указать `src` папку с условием `все файлы, кроме`, перечислить какие файлы в этой директории не сжимать.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что после сжатия результирующий файл combine.js помещается в тот же каталог, за которым идет наблюдение. Исключите его из наблюдения: `gulp.watch(['./www/js/**/*.js', '!./www/js/combine.js'], ['compress-js']);`

Comment: Почему-то при изменении js файла компилится и css: `[16:59:09] Starting 'compress-js'...
[16:59:11] Finished 'compress-js' after 1.74 s
    write www/css/main.css

[16:59:13] Finished 'compress-css' after 3.81 s`

Answer (score 0):

В соседнем ответы вам правильно подсказали. Вы компилируете JS в туже папку, из которой взят исходник. Вообще правильно хранить исходники в отдельных папках и компилировать их в директорию сборки, к примеру под названием public. Логика такая - исходники не должны зависеть от скомпилированных вариантов.